# Prove the Following Property of an Ultrafilter

Tags: set-theory, filters

In her text  Introduction to Modern Set Theory , Judith Roitman defined a filter of a set $X$ as a family $F$ of subsets of $X$ so that: 
(a) If $A \in F$ and $X \supseteq B \supseteq A$ then $B \in F$. 
(b) If $A_1, ... ,A_n$ are elements of $F$, so is $A1 \cap ... \cap An$.

Then she proceeded to define an ultrafilter as such:  "If $F$ is proper and, for all $A_n \subseteq X$, either $A \in F$ or $X-A \in F$, we say that $F$ is an ultrafilter."

Now, suppose that $F$ is an ultrafilter on a set $X$. Prove that if $X = S_1 \cup ... \cup S_n$, then some $S_n \in F$.  She wrote, "If not, then, since no $S_i \in F$, $F$ is proper, and each $X-S_i \in F$.  So $\bigcap_{i \le n}(X-S_i) \in F$.  But $\bigcap_{i \le n}(X-S_i) = \emptyset \notin F$.

What I did not understand was that if she already defined an ultrafilter as proper, why did she have to say "since no $S_i \in F$, $F$ is proper ..."?  My thinking was that if $X = S_1 \cup ... \cup S_n$ is not an element of $F$, then by the fact that $F$ is an ultrafilter, $X^c$ = $\bigcap_{i \le n}(X-Si) \in F$, but $X^c = \emptyset \notin F$, creating a contradiction.  Did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She's not saying that $F$ is proper *because* no $S_i\in F$. I'd just about bet that she meant something like this:

> If not, then since no $S_i\in F$, then each $X\setminus S_i\in F$, and therefore $\bigcap_{i\le n}S_i F$. But then $\varnothing=\bigcap_{i\le n}S_i \in F$, which is impossible, since $F$ is proper.

**Added:** In other words, the statement that $F$ is proper inadvertently crept in before it was really wanted. My guess is that it’s simply a small slip of the mind or pen on Judy’s part that wasn’t noticed in any revisions.

Comment: Ok, sir.  Probably it was a just a mistake ....

Answer (score 2):

If I were writing such text,  I would have pointed it out in order to remind the reader of this. Especially when in just one sentence we derived a contradiction from it.

Comment: Plus, I still haven't figured out how if no $S_i \in F$, then $F$ is proper ....

Comment: That's not what it says. It lists the things we know about $F$. Then it derives the contradiction.

Comment: @AndyTam The improper filter on $X$ contains all the subsets of $X$. So if you have a filter $F$ on $X$ and you have at least one subset of $X$ that is *not* in $F$, then you know that $F$ is proper.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Blass:  Yes sir.  I see it now.